# Attribute passed through signal/slot connexion loses its type

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qthread

I am writing a package to send/receive frames over a CAN bus monitored by a GUI, using pyqt5. 
Here is the process :

0. Create A new QThread object (called tx_thread)separate from main window thread.
1. Create a TxWorker (class inheriting from QObject), called tx_worker.
2. Move it to tx_thread
3. Setup signal/slot connexion
4. Start tx_thread
5. Create a TxJob object (class inheriting from QObject)
6. Move it to tx_thread
7. Pass it to tx_worker through signal/slot connexion, so that tx_worker handles the TxJob by itself afterwards.

I have used the above process many times for other cases and it usually works perfectly.
However, in this case I get an error : it seems that the TxJob object "loses" its type during the call through signal/slot and is reverted to a mere QObject without the additional TxJob attributes. 
That is very weird to me because I specified the type of signal parameter and slot signature.

**Does anyone understand what the issue is and what I should do to fix it ?**

-- **EDIT** -- 
I have found a workaround to avoid the error : I send constructor parameters instead of the object in the signal emit method, then I create the TxJob object from within the receiving thread.

**Nevertheless**, I want to understand *why my first approach did not work*, for the sake of my knowledge in python and/or Qt. 
 I would be glad to get any leads on this.

--

I condensed my code into the following files to reproduce the issue. 
When executing *test_main.py*, I get :

> Before emitting signal, type is : <class 'test_tx_job.TxJob'> 
> After entering slot, type is : <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'> 
> 'QObject' object has no attribute 'set_active'

The error arises when executing `job.set_active(True)` in method `add_tx_job()` of class TxWorker

*test_main.py*

```
import sys
from test_iocan import IoCan
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    io_can = IoCan()
    io_can.new_tx_task()
    io_can.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())         # Start event loop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*test_iocan.py*

```
from test_tx_job import TxJob
from test_tx_worker import TxWorker
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow


class IoCan(QMainWindow):
    sig_add_tx_job = pyqtSignal(TxJob)

    def __init__(self):
        super(IoCan, self).__init__()
        self.tx_thread = QThread(parent=self)                         # Step 0
        self.tx_worker = TxWorker()                                   # Step 1
        self.tx_worker.moveToThread(self.tx_thread)                   # Step 2
        self.sig_add_tx_job.connect(self.tx_worker.add_tx_job)        # Step 3
        self.tx_thread.start(priority=QThread.TimeCriticalPriority)   # Step 4

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """Override of the close event default method."""
        # Needed to cleanly terminate threads
        self.threads_stop()
        super(IoCan, self).closeEvent(event)

    def new_tx_task(self):
        new_job = TxJob()                     # Step 5
        new_job.moveToThread(self.tx_thread)  # Step 6
        print('Before emitting signal, type is : ' + str(type(new_job)))
        self.sig_add_tx_job.emit(new_job)     # Step 7

    def threads_stop(self):
        self.tx_thread.quit()
        self.tx_thread.wait()
```

*test_tx_worker.py*

```
from test_tx_job import TxJob
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot


class TxWorker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TxWorker, self).__init__()
        self.tx_jobs = []

    @pyqtSlot(TxJob)
    def add_tx_job(self, job: TxJob):  # Called at step 7 in tx_thread
        print('After entering slot, type is : ' + str(type(job)))
        try:
            job.set_active(True)
        except AttributeError as err:
            print(err.args[0])
        else:
            print(type(job))
            self.tx_jobs.append(job)
```

*test_tx_job.py*

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject


class TxJob(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TxJob, self).__init__()
        self._is_active = False

    def set_active(self, value: bool):
        self._is_active = value
```

Comment: Does `TxJob` *really* need to inherit from `QObject`? If you use an ordinary python class, your example will work fine (without the `job.moveToThread`, of course). Passing an unparented `QObject` as a signal parameter is generally not a good idea, for the reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18025182/984421).

Comment: I understand your point, but I would prefer all instances of `TxJob` to be handled by the unique instance of `TxWorker` in a separate `QThread` from GUI thread. That is why I call `moveToThread`, which can only be used on `QObject` type. 
I fear that not moving `TxJob` objects to _tx_thread_ would result in concurrent thread accesses to the object and risk causing deadlocks.
And I still want to understand why the object class changes during signal-slot access;

Comment: In the meantime, I will apply your suggestion to not pass a QObject as signal parameter : I will just send the constructor parameters and create the TxJob from within the slot.